# grouping json data in a specific format

Tags: javascript, lodash

My base data is as following..

```
 [{
        month: 'Jan',
        cat: 'A',
        val: 20
    },{
        month: 'Jan',
        cat: 'B','
        val: 5
    },{
        month: 'Jan',
        cat: 'C',
        val: 10
    },{
        month: 'Feb',
        cat: 'A',
        val: 30
    },{
        month: 'Feb',
        cat: 'B',
        val: 10
    },{
        month: 'Feb',
        cat: 'C',
        val: 20
    }];
```

I need to convert it into the following using javascript preferably lodash..

```
 [{
        selectedmonth: 'Jan',
        data:[{
        mycat: 'A',
        myval: 20
    },{
        mycat: 'B',
        myval: 5
    },{
        mycat: 'C',
        myval: 10
    }
       ]
    }, {
        selectedmonth: 'Feb',
        data:[{
        mycat: 'A',
        myval: 30
    },{
        mycat: 'B',
        myval: 10
    },{
        mycat: 'C',
        myval: 20
    }
       ]
    }]
```

I understand the lodash groupby - month call would do the groupby but it does it in a different format..

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an object as a hashtable for the reference to the result array.

```js
var array = [{ month: 'Jan', cat: 'A', val: 20 }, { month: 'Jan', cat: 'B', val: 5 }, { month: 'Jan', cat: 'C', val: 10 }, { month: 'Feb', cat: 'A', val: 30 }, { month: 'Feb', cat: 'B', val: 10 }, { month: 'Feb', cat: 'C', val: 20 }],
    grouped = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.month]) {
        this[a.month] = { selectedmonth: a.month, data: [] };
        grouped.push(this[a.month]);
    }
    this[a.month].data.push({ mycat: a.cat, myval: a.val });

}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Thanks, just want to understand the code..what does this[a.month] mean??

Comment: `this` is an object, which is created by `Object.create(null)` and used in the callback. the object holds the reference to the result array, with month as the key.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using lodash, you can make use of [groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) to group items by `month` and then use [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) to transform the items according to your criteria.

```
var result = _(collection)
  .map(v => _.mapKeys(v, (v, k) => 'my' + k))
  .groupBy('mymonth')
  .map((data, selectedmonth) => ({
    selectedmonth,
    data: _.map(data, item => _.omit(item, 'mymonth'))
  })).value();
```

```js
var collection = [{
  month: 'Jan',
  cat: 'A',
  val: 20
}, {
  month: 'Jan',
  cat: 'B',
  val: 5
}, {
  month: 'Jan',
  cat: 'C',
  val: 10
}, {
  month: 'Feb',
  cat: 'A',
  val: 30
}, {
  month: 'Feb',
  cat: 'B',
  val: 10
}, {
  month: 'Feb',
  cat: 'C',
  val: 20
}];

var result = _(collection)
  .map(v => _.mapKeys(v, (v, k) => 'my' + k))
  .groupBy('mymonth')
  .map((data, selectedmonth) => ({
    selectedmonth,
    data: _.map(data, item => _.omit(item, 'mymonth'))
  })).value();

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: 'data' has to be mapped such that 'cat' is changed to 'mycat' and 'val' changed to 'myval'

Comment: thanks.. just trying to understand what would happen if 'cat' had to be changed to 'mycat' and 'val' changed to 'selectedval'